# React useState only updates twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have a react image gallery that is driven off an array of objects and within each object is an array of image paths.
I've created a next function used with an onClick that increments the "imgPos" variable which is the array position. However, after the initial image changes, it stops working for the next clicks.
(FYI- I've console logged to confirm that the logic is working fine but the image is not updating...see screen capture below).

Sample Code:

```
const [imgPos, setImgPos] =useState(0)

export const FeaturedList = [
    {id: 0,
    street: "5228 Chelsea St",
    city: "La Jolla",
    beds: 5,
    baths: 8,
    sqft: 8878,
    mainimg: './images/5228main.webp' ,  
    images: ['./images/5228main.webp','./images/5228(2).webp','./images/52283.webp','./images/5228(4).webp','./images/5228(5).webp','./images/5228(6).webp','./images/5228(7).webp'] ,
    price: '$12,995,000' ,          
},
...
```

The function:

```
  const nextimg = () =>{
    if((imgPos + 1) > (FeaturedList[0].images.length -1)) {
        setImgPos(imgPos = 0)
       console.log("I'm the new imgPos#" + imgPos + "The length minus 1 is" + "FeaturedList[0].images.length -1")
    } else{
    setImgPos(imgPos + 1);
   console.log("There are 7 images for this object. The current imgPos  is:"  +  imgPos )
}
```

Here is where the imgPos variable is utilized:

```
 return(
     
    <div className="ft-disp-sec" style={{backgroundImage:`URL(${FeaturedList[0].images[imgPos]})`,backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundSize: 'cover', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', height: "100vh",}}>
<div className="ft-disp-arrows">
<img src={prev} className="ft-disp-prev" onClick={previmg}/>
  <img src={next} className="ft-disp-next" onClick={nextimg}/>
  </div>
  </div>
    )
}
```

Below is the console log. the second line where it states "The current impPos is:1 is the last time the image changes. No matter how many times you click it does not update again. Also, I noticed the console.log for setImgPos(imgPos = 0) never fires regardless of how many times I click the button.

[image]

Can you please advise on what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in React but I think the way you are setting the state in the setter function is not working as expected.

Try using the state setter like this `setImgPos(prevState => prevState = 0)` and `setImgPos(prevState => prevState += 1)`

Comment: Good suggestion but it's still working the same. The only difference is when the console log shows the reset back to zero is working once it reaches 5 but the images are not changing.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-snyder-git6dn?file=/src/App.js) Is a Codesandbox in which I have a simplified setup for this.

You should never mutate the state variable directly like you do with `setImgPos(imgPos = 0)`.
You can either give the value directly like `setImgPos(0)` or give a callback function in which you increment or decrement the previous state `setImgPos(prevState => prevState + 1)`

So with this in mind we can take you nextImg function and change it accordingly

```
  const nextimg = () => {

    if(imgPos >= FeaturedList[0].images.length - 1) {
        setImgPos(0)
    } else{
        setImgPos(prevState => prevState + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not work either. I actually received "prevstate" is notdefined & "nextImg" is not defined.  I trried to work around them using your concept but that did not work either.

Comment: I just edited answer and sandbox. The naming was wrong. it should be prevState and if you call the nextimg function please verify that they are both written the same because I have written it in camelCase like `nextImg` but if you defined it as nextimg you have to call it as `nextimg`

Comment: No luck. I would add the console errors but it's too many characters for a reply. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I once again have updated the code sandbox. Now to match more with your example. The only difference is that I have to use require to import the image. It could also help if you can open up a code sandbox yourself, paste and test your code and link it here so we could see for ourselfs.

Comment: I commented out the background code and tested the exact same code with an image tag and it works fine. I guess you can't change background images like this in React. Another hook is probably required. I'll just use the image element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the filenames. An img tag doesn't have any problems detecting they are different file names but when you use background it appears to skipover the ending(2)(3)(4)...etc so it wasn't re-rendering.